# Accessing Plist from user documents instead of NSBundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist, nsbundle

Hello I have the following code which works perfect, it finds the Plist and assigns the `NSDictionary` to my `NSArray` called landingSites. The only problem is I want the user to be able to add sites so need to store the Plist in the user documents instead of the `NSBundle`:

```
plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
dictionaryKeys = [newDictionary allKeys];
self.landingSites = [dictionaryKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
self.dictionaryFromPlist = newDictionary;

[Picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

for(NSString *parent in dictionaryKeys) 
{
    NSDictionary *parentData = [dictionaryFromPlist objectForKey:parent];
    NSArray *child = [parentData objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", child);
}
```

So far I have produced the code below, but whenever I run the program, the if-statement ALWAYS executes as if the plist in never copied to the user documents. Also I do not know how to attach the `NSDictionary` contents to my landingSites array as I did above. Please help

```
 (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            NSLog(@"copying database to users documents");
            NSString *pathToSettingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathToSettingsBundle toPath:path error:&error];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"users database already configured");
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked that `Data.plist` does not exist in the `Documents` directory? If `fileExistsAtPath:` is returning `YES` then there's a reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask,YES);
```

`NSDocumentationDirectory` is wrong.  You are looking for `NSDocumentDirectory` or `NSLibraryDirectory`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thank you @Putz1103, must have been a typing error, the code now works. Lastly could you please answer the latter part of my issue. How do I enter the contents of the NSDictonary into my landingSites NSArray as I did in the first code block where I used the NSBundle

Comment: If it's the exact same file (type at least) then the exact same way.  Reading a plist file from the bundle and reading a plist file from another directory act the exact same way.